# Weighted mesh doesn't animate when I import it to unity

Tags: armature

I've made a model that is a single mesh for a head and attached it to an armature, the model doesn't have a body, it's just an object where a head would be. The idea behind this is so it can move this object around like a head would move, but it is just a floating object.

I used a child of constraint on the mesh to attach it to the head bone of the armature, however when I import it into unity and test it with a simple walking animation, it doesn't move. I'm not sure why this is, because when I use pose mode in blender and move the head bone, the entire mesh moves with it, but it just won't animate in unity.

Comment: You can't use blenders constarint system and expect unity to understand that. The only thing unity (or any othe game engine for that matter)  understands is a weigthed mesh and maybe shape keys. You need to create vertex groups and use the armature modifier.

Comment: This fixed my problem, had to learn how to use vertex groups and that sorted it. On a side note the animation I was testing it with wasn't importing properly, I imported the whole package and it worked after that.